# What happens to things in SIP restricted folders when upgrading to 10.11?

Tags: macos, upgrade

What will happen to changes made to folders such as`/System` or `/bin` (full list [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899)) when upgrading to El Capitan or Sierra?

Comment: As these have always been Apple controlled folders I would expect that any upgrade even before SIP would replace them all with what should be there for the new OS. I don't think SIP changes this behaviour

Comment: @Mark I'm talking more like things added to `/System/Graphics/` or kexts added to the `/System` folder. They haven't been touched by previous upgrades.